# Firebase admin sdk java client suddenly started to return 401 error with status code "unknown-error"

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am using [firebase admin sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to push mobile notifications(firebase cloud messaging). I have successfully set up it and it worked about year at google cloud kubernetes engine. Then it stopped to work. Here is stacktrace what I am receiving at backend:

```
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Unexpected HTTP response with status: 401; body: null
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.newException(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:307) ~[firebase-admin-6.12.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.createExceptionFromResponse(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:212) ~[firebase-admin-6.12.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.send(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:128) ~[firebase-admin-6.12.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$1.execute(FirebaseMessaging.java:139) ~[firebase-admin-6.12.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$1.execute(FirebaseMessaging.java:136) ~[firebase-admin-6.12.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.firebase.internal.CallableOperation.call(CallableOperation.java:36) ~[firebase-admin-6.12.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.send(FirebaseMessaging.java:106) ~[firebase-admin-6.12.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.send(FirebaseMessaging.java:90) ~[firebase-admin-6.12.1.jar!/:na]
```

Status code from FirebaseMessagingException is `unknown-error`. I am using gradle dependency `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.12.1`.

My server code of FirebaseApp initialization(kotlin):

```
val credentials = GoogleCredentials
        .fromStream(FileInputStream(firebaseAppCredentials))
        .createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"))
val options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
        .setCredentials(credentials)
        .build()
val firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)
```

I have verified `firebaseAppCredentials` contains path to file with [firebase service account](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/service-accounts).
Here is sending code(kotlin):

```
val message = Message.builder()
        .setNotification(notification)
        .setToken(registrationToken)
        .build()
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(firebaseApp).send(message)
```

Can you help to find out how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented raw protocol(raw http requests) and it started to work. For some reasons Firebase Admin SDK java library haven't used auth token in http request. I suspect it is related to the fact that I have configured GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS evn var to service account from gcloud project but firebase app was initialized with service account from firebase project. It is intentional, I am using multiple gcloud projects but for FCM only one project is used.

It looks like some bug/feature in `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.12.1` and it is reproduced only at cloud env.